# How to update Git client for Windows while keeping the old settings?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I installed Git for Windows many years ago. I was using it with Cygwin. I also have Sourcetree and there were some problems with many Git repositories in my computer (but not anymore).

Now, my old Git won't work with GitHub so I must update it. I started the installation of Git and it's asking me bunch of questions. I don't remember what I chose for these three years ago. I don't want to take a chance and break anything.

So, is there a way to update Git without changing any settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply download and install the git msi.

Git "reads" the current configuration and will check out the current configuration you have on your local machine, so all the checked are the defaults or your current configuration is there are any.

If you want to be sure that nothing will get lost you can simply save the current git configuration of your user which is found under your `Users\<login user>/.gitconfig`

---

You can also verify that nothing was changed using the following commands:

```
# print out the current configuration with the path to each configuration
# file so you can track the configuration and the origin of the key/value
git config -l --show-origin
```

Save the output to file or in any other way you wish to save it, install git and execute the configuration list again and compare if there are any major changed besides the expected ones (git configuration updates).

[image]

Comment: For me, installing the Windows download did not disturb earlier config file changes. ``git update-git-for-windows`` failed due to a curl issue.

Answer (score 1):

> How should i remember what i did chose for these 3 years ago!? I don't want to chance, meaning BROKE anything!

You don't have to: you installed Git with Cygwin.
This has nothing to do with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), which by the way, you can simply uncompress and add to your PATH (using the portable version [`PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe)).

Plus, once installed, a simple command "`git update`" will be enough to, later on, upgrade Git for Windows! See [PR 155](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/155).

Just make sure your PATH does not reference Cygwin, only Git.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've already upgraded [*Git for Windows* from this website](https://git-scm.com/) to one of the newer versions, the next time you can run the following command to automatically check for updates and install them.

```
git update-git-for-windows
```

The Git installer would show the options you chose before. Simply not changing the options would make sure they are used exactly as before.

Newer Git installers have a checkbox at the bottom called "Only show new options". Enabling this checkbox means your previous settings would be used exactly as before and would not be asked for again.

*Regardless, it's a good idea to go through all the options and check if they still make sense for your present workflow or need to be changed. Don't worry about what you did many years in the past. Your needs change over time, and you're unlikely to break anything.*